# TSQL Query data from inner select or join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a TSQL query that is in its very basic format:

My goal of this query is to find all data where `L.localeID = x`. As you can see its in the second inner select statement in the query.

I have it in the inner select as there cold be multiple results in that table linked to the parent table.

How can I go about getting this query in the correct format? Do I need to join the table a specific way or will the sub query work?

```
     SELECT A.[trainingEventID],
        A.[teTitle],
        A.[teDesc],
        A.[teSource],
        A.[teType],
        A.[teMedium],
        A.[teFlag],
        A.[teCreator],
        A.[teCreated],
        seg.[segmentDate],
        convert(decimal(10, 2), seg.[nonProdHrs]) as nonProdHrs,
        (
             SELECT emp.[FirstName] as trainerFirst,
                    emp.[LastName] as trainerLast
            FROM BS_Training_Trainers as trn
            LEFT OUTER JOIN employeeTable as emp
            ON trn.trainerEmpID = emp.EmpID
            WHERE trn.segmentID = seg.teSegmentID
            FOR    XML PATH ('trainer'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('trainers')
        ),
        (
         SELECT L.[recordID],
                L.[segmentID],
                L.[localeID],
                L.[teammateCount],
                L.[leaderCount]
            FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS L
            WHERE seg.teSegmentID = L.segmentID
            FOR    XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('details')
        )
        FROM   [red].[dbo].[BS_TrainingEvents] AS A
        INNER JOIN dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS seg
        ON A.[trainingEventID] = seg.[trainingEventID]
```

*UPDATED*

Here is an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe3cf/11

Comment: So the above doesn't work? 
Since the subquery which pulls back L.[LocaleID] is already included and joined to A. You could just do where Seg.LocaleID = X?

Comment: I'm not querying the `seg `table; I am looking in the inner select `L.`

Comment: Sorry by bad. I misread. I would take the subquery from the Select and place it as a join, then in the select place L.* in there to select all the values from L then you can apply a condition to it. Optionally you can wrap the whole of what you have into a subquery `SELECT * FROM ([WHOLEQUERY]) a Where a.record_ID = x`

Comment: I think the issue I would run into with the join is not being able to use the `FOR XML`. I need the ability to show the event and then all of its segments attached to it which is why I had it as the inner select Just not sure how to query by that inner data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XQuery to check if the XML generated from `dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails` contains `<localeID>200</localeID>`. For that you would need to define the XML column in such a way that you could reference it in WHERE. One way would be to use CROSS APPLY:

```
CROSS APPLY
    (
     SELECT L.[recordID],
            L.[segmentID],
            L.[localeID],
            L.[teammateCount],
            L.[leaderCount]
        FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS L
        WHERE seg.teSegmentID = L.segmentID
        FOR    XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('details')
    ) AS x (SegmentDetailsXML)
```

Then you would reference the value in the main select as `x.SegmentDetailsXML` and would also be able to use it in the WHERE clause [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe3cf/16):

```
WHERE
    x.SegmentDetailsXML.exist('/details/detail/localeID[text() = "200"]') = 1
```

or, if `200` is supposed to be passed through a variable name, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe3cf/18):

```
WHERE
    x.SegmentDetailsXML.exist('/details/detail/localeID[text() = sql:variable("@localeID")]') = 1
```